# How to have Bootstrap modals using knockout data bindings?

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, bootstrap-modal

I can't figure out how to make my Bootstrap modals represent content through knockout data-binding.

Regarding the example below, how can I make the shortName to be correctly displayed in the body of each modal?

I have a viewmodel with:

```js
function Stock(stockName) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(stockName);
  self.shortName = ko.observable();
  ...
}
...
function StockViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  stock1 = new Stock('Facebook');
  stock2 = new Stock('Twitter');
  self.stockList = ko.observableArray([stock1, stock2]);
  ...
  self.updateStockData = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/stockShortName/" + self.name(),
      type: "GET",
      success: function(response) {
        self.shortName(response);
      }
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new StockViewModel());
```

In the view I have:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Stock Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: stockList">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'stock-template', data: $data}"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="stock-detail-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Here comes the body: ...</p>
        <div data-bind="text: shortName"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/html" id="stock-template">
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#stock-detail-modal" id="1234">
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
  </a>
</script>
```

Comment: http://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/#modal

Answer (score 0):

You can provide another property as part of StockViewModel which will act as a container for the selected value. This property will be the source of information for the modal. So when a user select a stock, store the selected stock information in this property so the modal will be updated with the right info.

```
function Stock(stockName) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(stockName);
  self.shortName = ko.observable();
  ...

  // I moved it here as from your code you're trying get self.name and modify self.shortName which only exist here
  self.updateStockData = function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "/stockShortName/" + self.name(),
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response) {
      self.shortName(response);
    }
  });
}
...
function StockViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  var stock1 = new Stock('Facebook');
  var stock2 = new Stock('Twitter');
  self.stockList = ko.observableArray([stock1, stock2]);

  // Here is the container, for simplicity we can assign default value to it
  self.selectedStock = ko.observable(stock1);

  // Then if a user select a stock, we update data that will be shown on the modal
  self.selectStock = function(data, event){
    self.selectedStock(data);
  }
  ...
}

ko.applyBindings(new StockViewModel());
```

For the html, you just need make sure you show `shortName` from the new property and update `selectedStock` whenever a user select on a stock.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="stock-detail-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Here comes the body: ...</p>
        <div data-bind="text: selectedStock().name"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: selectedStock().shortName"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="stock-template">
  <a data-bind="click: $root.selectStock" data-toggle="modal" href="#stock-detail-modal" id="1234">
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
  </a>
</script>
```